# Does blizzard silently update the AI?

Tags: starcraft-2

It seems that the AI was at least twice updated without this being noted in the patch notes. First major thing that i saw was a much better defense against a cannon rush. Then patch 1.1.2 went live and I played a few games against hard AI to test the changes. I was very surprised to see that the second attack wave from my protoss enemy (i was zerg) came with 1,1,1 upgrades. I think before the patch even Very Hard AIs did not upgrade armor/weapons/shields at all (or at least not so soon).

Is it just me or did someone else notice this? Why is blizzard doing this and NOT mentioning it in patch notes? I can understand why they wanted to update the AI, but why not mention it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at World of Warcraft (Blizzard's other huge game) and their patch history, every patch there was a list of "undocumented patch changes" posted on the forums by players. Often these lists were as long as (or longer than!) the actual patch notes.

They have listed a few reasons for this, that I recall:

- Some changes are minor and don't warrant a patch notes entry
- Some changes are technical or under-the-hood and don't concern most players
- Some changes are exploit-fixes, and they'd rather not publish exploit information
- Some changes are tentative and it's unknown if they will make the current patch. If a change is added to or removed from a patch at the last minute, the docs may not be updated.
- Sometimes some department at Blizzard drops the ball and forgets to document something.

Overall, these games are enormously-complicated software projects, and with hundreds of people working on them, and so sometimes documentation slips through the cracks.

In the specific case of AI changes for SC2, my guess is that they felt these changes were not important enough to be of interest to the majority of players, and/or that these changes were just bug-fixes (shoring up the AI against cheese rushes etc). This is just my guess though.

Answer (score 4):

There are always changes that don't make it into patch notes.

Far as I can tell, they try to list everything that affects human multiplayer gameplay, but AI is less important in that sense.

Comment: Upvoted, but i feel like Wikwockets answer is more detailed so i accepted that one instead of this one.

Comment: @PeterK Cool. Wikwocket's answer is better. :)